# Nicest way to run some JS immediately after an element has loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say you've got some HTML,

```
<input id="mytextbox" type="text" value="hello world" />
```

And you want to do some magic on that textbox as soon as it's loaded. Maybe add some kind of widget, or button beside it, whatever. There's 2 ways of doing this that I'm aware of. You can throw some jQuery like this in the `<head>`

```
$(function() {
    $('#mytextbox').magic();
});
```

And that'll run once the *entire DOM* is ready, but what if we want it sooner? As soon the element has loaded?

We can put the JS immediately after the element:

```
<input id="mytextbox" type="text" value="hello world" />
<script>
    $('#mytextbox').magic();
</script>
```

But that's a bit messier, and why should we have to search the entire DOM for an element ID when we know exactly where it is? `onclick` events have a `this` argument. Isn't there some way we can do something like this...

```
<input id="mytextbox" type="text" value="hello world" onload="$(this).magic()" />
```

? Would be nicest solution IMO, but only the body has an `onload` event apparently, and no other event seems suitable. Are we basically left to solution #2 if we want some piece of code to run immediately after an element is loaded?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, your second snippet is the "best" (whatever that means, probably *fastest*) way to apply some Javascript to an element.

```
<input id="mytextbox" type="text" value="hello world" />
<script type="text/html">
    $('#mytextbox').magic();
</script>
```

You are not searching the entire *DOM* here. A call like this directly goes down to

```
document.getElementById('mytextbox');
```

which is more or less, just insta-access to the node.
Anyway, a practice like this betrays the idea of unobtrusive Javascript. I wouldn't know a reason why you shouldn't apply some code when the `DOMContentLoaded` event fires (which is abstracted away by jQuerys `.ready()`).

Comment: What if you have a really large page, and some fancy JS-enhanced input widgets at the top of the page. You've just made them unusable until the whole page has loaded. Or maybe some important event needs to fire when you perform action X, but you missed the event because you were waiting for the DOM to load to add your handlers.

Comment: And you're assuming that browsers use some kind of dictionary/hashmap to look up elements by ID? It would be logical for them to do so, but who knows. Would still be nice if we could tie and event/function to an element at the same time it's being created: no lookup, and no delay.

Answer (score 1):

Since javascript includes are generally blocking (unless you load it async ofcourse), it is always a good idea to put your javascript as low as possible on the page. That way the user won't have to wait for your javascript to load while browsing through the page.

So the question here is, do you really want it to load immediately after that element. Or simply at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Yes. That specifically was the assumption I was making; that I *do* want it to load immediately. For less important things, sure, put them at the bottom of the page, but if it needs to fire ASAP...then it should fire ASAP.